# django nginx DisallowedHost

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx

i'm using aws ubuntu instance and nginx
i tried to reach my app and i get this error :

```
DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '34.227.190.72'. You may need to add '34.227.190.72' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://34.227.190.72/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: DisallowedHost
Exception Value:    
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '34.227.190.72'. You may need to add '34.227.190.72' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Exception Location: /home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/http/request.py, line 149, in get_host
Python Executable:  /home/ubuntu/env/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.10
Python Path:    
['/home/ubuntu/authentication',
 '/home/ubuntu/env/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/ubuntu/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 31 May 2022 10:46:53 +0000
```

i tried to add my public address to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `setting.py` file but it doesn't work

my `setting.py` file :

```py
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['34.227.190.72', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting EC2 instance after modifying settings.py worked in my case.
I also found that if you are using supervisor, simply restarting supervisor also works, whenever making modification in settings.py file.

```
sudo systemctl restart supervisor
```